# Django 3 returns ModuleNotFound error after renaming the project

Tags: django

I renamed a django project and now I cannot start the WSGI server anymore. It is looking for an old name, but I have changed the name everywhere. Where is the server looking for the old name? The traceback is not helpful. I tried removing all `__pycache__` folders.

```
omics_server>python server.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "server.py", line 3, in <module>
    from omics_server.wsgi import application
  File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/omics_server/omics_server/wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
    application = get_wsgi_application()
  File "/home/ubuntu/miniconda3/envs/omics/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
    django.setup(set_prefix=False)
  File "/home/ubuntu/miniconda3/envs/omics/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 19, in setup
    configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
  File "/home/ubuntu/miniconda3/envs/omics/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 76, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/home/ubuntu/miniconda3/envs/omics/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 63, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/home/ubuntu/miniconda3/envs/omics/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 142, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/home/ubuntu/miniconda3/envs/omics/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'omics'
```

manage.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""Django's command-line utility for administrative tasks."""
import os
import sys


def main():
    os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'omics_server.settings')
    try:
        from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    except ImportError as exc:
        raise ImportError(
            "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
            "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
            "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
        ) from exc
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

omics_server/wsgi.py:

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'omics_server.settings')

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

And `grep omics omics_server/settings.py` returns:

```
ROOT_URLCONF = 'omics_server.urls'
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'omics_server', 'templates'),
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'omics_server.wsgi.application'
        'NAME': 'omics_server',
                              default='/var/www/html/omics/')
                               default='/omics/')
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'omics_server', "static"),
ASGI_APPLICATION = 'omics_server.routing.application'
```

Where else is server.py looking?

Answer (score 0):

I had a `celery.py` file containing the old name. Unfortunately, the traceback did not show where the error originated from.